# Convert file format while copying data using copy activity in Azure data factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am performing a copy activity to bring in data into the Azure data lake using Azure data factory. The file format is compressed(.gz) format.

I want to copy those files but want to change the format to .json instead of copying in the same original format(the .gz file contains inside a .json file).

Is there a mechanism to get this done in Azure data factory? I want to perform this because in further ETL process i will face issues with .gz format.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1:** Create Copy Activity.

**Step2:** Select .gz file as Source

**Step3:** Select gzip(.gz) as Compression type and Compression level as Optimal.

[image]

**Step4:** Select Sink as blob storage and run pipeline.

This will unzip your .gz file.